# Byte array image larger than 1,024 bytes in length, IE8

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8, arrays

I'm having problems getting byte array images larger than 1024 bytes in length. (IE8)

Is there any workaround ?

The problem is that pictures that contains more than 1024 bytes in length get's cut. In another word, not the entire picture gets displayed because the byte stream gets cut off.

Comment: what kind of problem you having?

Comment: IE8 limits data URIs to a maximum of 32KB. Otherwise, your question  makes no sense and I have no idea what you're talking about. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demo?